# valgrind massif ms_print prints 0x0: ??? instead of stack

Tags: memory-leaks, valgrind, massif

I use valgrind --tool massif to get the profile of memory, and then print it with ms_print. But 74% of memory shows `0x0: ???`, does it means 74% of memory leak?

->74.11% (503,526,238B) 0x0: ???
|
->24.66% (167,561,216B) 0x5051C66: ceph::buffer::raw_posix_aligned::raw_posix_aligned(unsigned int, unsigned int) (buffer.cc:393)

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't mean that there is a leak. It means that `massif` isn't able to get the source information for that point in the callstack.

If you want to detect leaks you should be using `memcheck` (as a rule).